# Cakephp issue with "OR" and "AND" array with find function

Tags: cakephp

As Cakephp's [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) suggest, I have a column on which I want to put "OR" condition for matching multiple values and AND condition with other columns.

SQL :

```
SELECT * FROM site_logs 
WHERE action LIKE "Facebook%" OR action LIKE "Twitter%" AND 
created >= "2013-06-29" 
GROUP BY "ip address"
```

CakePHP :

```
$conditions = array(
        'OR' => array(
            'SiteLogs.action like' => 'Facebook%'
            'SiteLogs.action like' => 'Twitter%'
        ),
        'SiteLogs.created >=' => '2013-06-29'
    );
 $this->SiteLogs->find('all',
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'group'     => 'ip address'
 )
```

Generated SQL have records only for "twitter" data, because "OR" array have all the elements with same key which will overwrite each other.

GENERATED SQL;

```
SELECT `site_logs`.* FROM `site_logs` 
WHERE `site_logs`.`action` LIKE "Twitter%" AND  
    site_logs`.`created` >= "2013-06-29" 
GROUP BY `site_logs`.`ip address`
```

What should I do to get all the values from "OR" array? Am I missing something?

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but your desired SQL is a little ambiguous.  When you have multiple AND & OR conditions, you should group them into sets so it's clear how you want MySQL to execute them.  In your case, I think you want `WHERE (action LIKE a OR action LIKE b) AND created > dt`... which is much different than `WHERE action LIKE a OR (action LIKE b AND created > dt)`

Comment: @StevenMoseley : I was getting confused by cakephp's manual, thanks for your help sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is this.  Enclose the similar OR clauses each into their own arrays to prevent overlap of keys.

```
$conditions = array(
    'OR' => array(
        array('SiteLogs.action like' => 'Facebook%'),
        array('SiteLogs.action like' => 'Twitter%')
    ),
    'SiteLogs.created >=' => '2013-06-29'
);
$this->SiteLogs->find('all',
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'group'     => 'ip address'
);
```

This should produce SQL like this.  There's an extraneous set of parentheses around each of the `LIKE` conditions, but this is unavoidable with Cake, and it won't affect the execution of the query at all.

```
SELECT * 
FROM site_logs 
WHERE 
    ((action LIKE "Facebook%") OR (action LIKE "Twitter%"))
    AND created >= "2013-06-29" 
GROUP BY "ip address"
```